# How can I use virtualenv to use 32-bit and 64-bit Python in Windows?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have 64-bit Python (2.7.5) installed at `C:\Python27` and 32-bit Python at `C:\Python27_32`.

I would like to use virtualenv to set up a 32-bit virtual environment that I can switch into when I need to use 32-bit Python.  Once that environment is set up, I plan to edit the `bin\activate` file to change all the necessary paths to point to the 32-bit directories.

However, when I try to create the virtual environment, I get the following error:

```
> virtualenv --python=C:\Python27_32\python.exe foo

Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\Python27_32\python.exe
PYTHONHOME is set.  You *must* activate the virtualenv before using it
New python executable in foo\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools...............
  Complete output from command C:\Users\<user>\Drop...o\Scripts\python.exe -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])

" C:\Python27\lib\site...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 278, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 238, in main
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/package_index.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 71, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2577, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 979, in main
    no_pip=options.no_pip)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1091, in create_environment
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 611, in install_setuptools
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 583, in _install_req
    cwd=cwd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1057, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command C:\Users\<user>\Drop...o\Scripts\python.exe -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])

" C:\Python27\lib\site...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg failed with error code 1
```

It seems to be doing imports in the 64-bit folder instead of in the 32-bit folder.  I'm not sure if it's because of the way my environment variables are set up, or because I installed virtualenv under 64-bit Python in the first place.

These are my user environment variables:

```
Path: %PYTHONHOME%;C:\Python27\Scripts
PYTHONHOME: C:\Python27
PYTHONPATH: C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\DLLs;
```

But if I change every `C:\Python27` to `C:\Python27_32` in my environment variables, then I can't virtualenv to run (`ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`).

This is my first time messing with virtualenv, so I'm sure I'm missing something basic.  How can I create a virtual environment that uses my 32-bit Python installation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your virtual env to run after you have changed your paths you will need to install virtualenv into the 32 bit python - there is nothing stopping you having a copy of virtualenv in each python.

Assuming you have python 2.7.c 64-bit as your default python and you have also installed python 2.7.x 32-bit *you would need both anyway* - also assuming that you are on windows your two pythons will be installed somewhere like:

`C:\Python27` and `C:\Python27_64`

With the latter on your path.

Also assuming that you have pip installed in both, *you will need it for virtualenv anyway* - to install virtualenv to the 32 bit python you can either run:

```
Path\To\32Bit\pip install virtualenv
```

or

```
set path=C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;%path%
rem The above should set your 32 bit to be found before your 64 bit
pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: Thanks Steve.  That worked.  Have questions about paths but will ask separately.

Comment: how can you exactly install virtual env into 32 bit python ?

Comment: @JPC See expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the 32Bit version first, and install the 64Bit version second (And you added python to path), Then you can use the updated python launcher (`py`) to create the 64Bit version of your virtualenv

`py -m venv my-env-name`

Answer (score -1):

in command prompt Use:

`set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
conda create -n virtualenv_name python=x.x anaconda`

The above can be found @ [How to install win-32 package on a 64-bit system with conda install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271187/how-to-install-win-32-package-on-a-64-bit-system-with-conda-install) I personally tried it and it worked successfully (32-bit python x.x installed). Using Anaconda is not necessary but it will install all of the anaconda packages like pandas.

Disclaimer: The comment below is a caution and not an attack on the answer submitted by anyone else.

As my friend told me "changing the path *manually* is discouraged, mostly because you'd have to inform other applications that use Python (and that you do not necessarily know of) to point to a different folder, and changes are not certain to be consistent across your system. In a way, virtualenvs do the same but in a cleaner and (sort of) predictable fashion".