# How to install win-32 package on a 64-bit system with conda install

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

I am looking to install the package [pyspharm](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyspharm/)

I am running the 64-bit Windows and have the 64-bit version of Anaconda installed.

However, whe I look for packages with

```
anaconda search -t conda pyspharm
```

It appears as if there are no channels with a package made for the win-64 platform.

Is there any way I can still install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crate a 32bit python environment:

```
set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
conda create -n py27_32bit python=2.7
enable py27_32bit
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge pyspharm
```

Just remember to `set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=` (set empty) if you are going to use the root environment 64bit

Comment: I still get the "PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-64 channels:" error even after activating the new 32bit environment

Comment: Don't unset the `CONDA_FORCE_32BIT` for as long as you need the 32 bit python, otherwise conda goes with 64bit, on a side note pyspharm only supports python27 so I edited the answer to do the py27_32bit environment.

Comment: It seems to me that using `set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT` in powershell does not seem to work properly. I was able to get around this by using the Anaconda CMD prompt.