# Python Poetry - How to Install 64-bit Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, python-poetry

How can I force Poetry to create a 64-bit virtual environment when I run `poetry install` for the first time?

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't find anything in the docs, or in the command line help for Poetry itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell what python executable should be used for the new environment by

```
poetry env use /path/to/python
```

before a

```
poetry install
```

This is only necessary if this is something different from what ever is used as `python` in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the GitHub it says how to install the package:
https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry

For example one option you can use is pip:

```
pip install --user poetry
```

Also there are docs which state another way:

https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation

Comment: Thanks for your response. Perhaps my question wasn't clear. I can install Poetry fine - however when I setup a new venv in poetry it defaults to being a 32 bit python install. I need to install a 64-bit python environment.

Comment: Might want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781266/how-can-i-use-virtualenv-to-use-32-bit-and-64-bit-python-in-windows